# javax Frame not displaying anything, arm64 processor

Tags: java, swing

Running 11.0.9. Open JDK is installed. JavaFX SDK is installed. Have run with correct JavaFX command and regular java command.

Running chromeos on an arm64 processor

Window originally starts as a sliver, but I've dragged it out to show that it's blank

[image: Originally Starts as a Sliver]

I've commented out the part of the code that references other code, but it won't display anything

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class NumericKeypadTester
    {
        public static void main (String[] args){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Numeric Keypad"); 
            //NumericKeypadPanel nkeyPanel = new NumericKeypadPanel();
  
            //frame.add(nkeyPanel);
  
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"it won't display anything"* By 'anything' DYM the frame title?  If not, what else do you expect it to display? BTW - Swing / AWT GUIs should be started on the Event Dispatch Thread.

Comment: @AndrewThompson In other code it references, I've added JLabels etc, it won't display those either. I've commented out that code for simplicity. But I've even set the width and height in other versions of the code and it still opens to a sliver size window.

What do you mean by starting it on the Event Dispatch Thread